# Help with shutdown during initial install, Xubuntu

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, shutdown

I have been pouring over anything I can find online regarding this issue and I am stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.  PC Setup is a AM+ processor, Radeon HD6700 series video card, 500gb Seagate HDD.  I have attempted install of Xubuntu 14.04.2 both from DVD and Flash drive, everytime I can get to the point where I name the install and set password but soon as I click next PC shuts down, no restart or anything as if I held the power button for shutdown.

First thought was power supply, swapped and did same thing.
Over heating, bios shows all temps well within range, nothing getting too hot.
Maybe video card error, removed the vid card and used on-board, same shutdown.
HDD tried another 160GB hard drive and still shut down.

At this point I am out of ideas and am thinking it may be the distro, or a compatibility issue with some component of my PC.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are able to run the 'live session' from the install media. If not it would seem possible that you have an image problem - did you check the md5 sum for the image? I guess that as you are looking at the xubuntu version you feel that your system spec will work better with a 'lighter' version. You could always try the lubuntu if so. Also maybe download the previous version, and see if you have the same problem. Finally if problems persist, and you feel capable maybe go for the alternate installer (this install a command line only).

Comment: The 'live' session i was able to start up to and messed around in the menus with no issue or shut downs.  I have recopied the image 3x onto the jump drive, Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 13.10 to try a older distro, and Xubuntu 14.04, all have the same issue.  Have not tried the command line, and to be honest not sure how to go about that.  Only thing I have not tried is 32bit version instead of the 64, just worried I will be cutting myself short not taking full advantage of my system.

Comment: If you have less then 4GB of RAM and don't plan on adding RAM, 32-bit is just fine!